# Software for calculating the volume and area of a lesion

Tags: software-development, software-testing

I have a picture like this (we want to calculating the volume   area of a lesion in Ophthalmology), my question :

Are there any  Software for calculating the volume and  area of a lesion?

or

Are there any  Software for calculating the volume  and  area of a picture?

Thanks[image]

Comment: Lots but none that will work without a scale reference - your example has an area of approx 3.72 square ojamafilps!